# Transform data other way around (groups of items instead of items with group references)

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do i make a function that can transform data of type `DevicesType` to `GroupsType` bellow?
So instead of getting list of devices saying what groups they are in I need a list of groups containing their respective devices.

```
type DevicesType = {
  id: string
  name: string
  status: "OK" | "FAULTY"
  groups: {
    id: string
    name: string
  }[]
}[]
```

```
type GroupsType = {
  id: string
  name: string
  devices: {
    id: string
    name: string
    status: "OK" | "FAULTY"
  }[]
}[]
```

Example data would be:

```
const devicesFromBackend: DevicesType = [
  {
    id: "d1",
    name: "device 1",
    status: "OK",
    groups: [
      {
        id: "g1",
        name: "group 1"
      },
      {
        id: "g2",
        name: "group 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "d2",
    name: "device 2",
    status: "FAULTY",
    groups: [
      {
        id: "g2",
        name: "group 2"
      },
      {
        id: "g3",
        name: "group 3"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I wanna do this to render tables for each group with list of their respective devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution that works with 0 dependencies

```js
function convertDevicesToGroups(devices: DevicesType): GroupsType {
    // Isolate groups
    const groups = devices.map((d) => d.groups).                            // Extract groups
        reduce((g, i = []) => i.concat(...g)).                              // Convert from 2D to 1D
        filter((g, i, self) => i === self.findIndex((e) => e.id === g.id)); // Remove duplicates


    return groups.map((group) => {
        const belongDevices = devices.
            filter((d) => d.groups.find((g) => g.id === group.id)).        // Filter devices that belog to a group
            map((d) => ({ id: d.id, name: d.name, status: d.status }));    // Extract required property

        return {
            ...group,
            devices: belongDevices,
        }; 
    });
}
```

[Jump to the playground for complete code and example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBuBLAxtAvFA3gKClRAJgFxQDOwATogHYDmuU1AhgLYQnlV0PlPACupEgCIA8gGlhUAD5RhAMQCCAVQAyAFQCawhrQoB7fmCFYGeQh0o16ePMzaWuNqAF8A2gF1sL7NlCRYBBQIUigMOCRUT19-aABxAyMw03NiMituO1Z2dKcGAiDUExxbfDTOazNGbMdK0t4BEzFJGTklNS0dPHcvHz9weMTjZITDMGjsADN%20amRgRH1qKGRF%20AgKYAjg0nV9UaNSAAoCyJCSLaKAShJ94ZLbAHoHqABJUn0AGz5oPTHSKpW1HIUF%20B2SJ22ADoWEwwIdjpcwgA%20KAESGg4yXSGlHG4vG4p5QACiAA9KEw5iChv98RQIAR%20Kh4bQADT4ZKeRFoFGISGA5B8Q6Q4W0S5Y-ESyWPZ4AYVW62AUEmBhYUAATDAoMB9FAAIwwKqlSaID7AdbMtmINmkCAfSZcnlhNAYG12yHG6gEF6eiAk%20EQB1QCCQwhOjC0EMEMUAbighIAShAWPo1qijB8UN9-r5SnSBBQlhjSNDYcyhoH7rjAcCAEa2xa0C4hcGFEKQw1442m80I5Go9HU900AjMwMR0PO8NDSNi7F4wnyE1miio1uhYAACz4UDrH30tC1OqYVLGHdxMLhve5UEOmDKJDRhDZ9hyaJf1uAfEED8hDUErhjUpCVJclKTpABHfhEDpAgoDAAxIA2EAczxPN%20ALFIpWFAcxhZM8cQhIoSF3Bsm1IPD8RcWMqhcS5o28Xxq0VQiQnkFUACEKQAawgT1zjXDkGEre85AIXVhAo2wXxEFi9Qkqo-yaCR5NKIsSDcDthNKCw5FocTJNxaTdKGOSOxcAzbC02wdOEWg1RUvEjNskz7LMqovG6SThJsgh7IspzZL8hTP0aER2g0bQLLUqANNxKzUhEOyHMMmpjLGdUuhxczNPwmzaAAZmSnEnIxKBCrc0oPNcbAPHo7AmK1EJFQwQE1g2MjdluI4WNINj9BYTjkB4z06PqxZ3g%20YM91oQ4zXIS4gA)

As well, I would recommend small improvements on your type for readability.

```js
type Group = {
  id: string
  name: string
  devices: {
    id: string
    name: string
    status: "OK" | "FAULTY"
  }[]
}

type Groups = Group[]

type Device = {
  id: string
  name: string
  status: "OK" | "FAULTY"
  groups: {
    id: string
    name: string
  }[]
}

type Devices = Device[]
```

The best things would be to remove that implicit circular dependency, but it requires more refactor that is not related to your current problem

Comment: Couldn't one skip the reducer and just use a flatmap?

Comment: True! I didn't know that function but after a quick research, I'm sure it can simplify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Presented below is one possible implementation (in JavaScript) to achieve the target:

```js
const devicesFromBackend = [
  {
    id: "d1",
    name: "device 1",
    status: "OK",
    groups: [
      {
        id: "g1",
        name: "group 1"
      },
      {
        id: "g2",
        name: "group 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "d2",
    name: "device 2",
    status: "FAULTY",
    groups: [
      {
        id: "g2",
        name: "group 2"
      },
      {
        id: "g3",
        name: "group 3"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const getGroups = (arr = devicesFromBackend) => (
  Object.values( // extract only the values of the object generated
    arr.reduce(  // iterate through the devices array using reduce
      (fin, {groups, ...rest}) => ({ // fin is the object generated (aggregated)
        ...fin, // they key (used in fin object) will be the group-id
        ...groups.reduce( // now iterate through the groups array
          (acc, {id, name}) => ({ // acc is the accumulator
            ...acc, // de-structured the group's name, id in above line
            [id]: id in fin // if the group-id already exists in fin-object
              ? { // populate the existing group details as-is
                ...fin[id], // then, add the new device into the existing group
                devices: fin[id].devices.concat([{
                  ...rest
                }])} // if group-id is not already present in fin, add it now
              : {id, name, devices: [{...rest}]}
          }),
          {}
        )
      }),
      {}
    )
  )
);

console.log(getGroups());
```

Approach is explained within the code, as comments. If required, these can be listed separately in this answer.